# Why is any subset of metric space not open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I thought I understood this "basic topology in metric spaces" stuff, but in order to prove any metric space is an open set convincingly, it seems I needed to understand any singleton is an open set and that understanding ruined all my notions, however flimsy they may have been.

Here's what I am working from:

Let (*X*, *d*) be a metric space, so the elements of the set *X* are points of *X*, and the image of any pair of such points under the map *d* is the distance between them.

I define a neighborhood of a point *a* of *X* for some positive real number *r* as the subset of *X* given by

*N*(*a*, *r*) = {*x* of *X* | d(*x*, *a*) < *r*}.

It seems the subset {*a*} of *X* is then a neighborhood of *a* since d(*a*, *a*) = 0 < *r*. And this holds for all points of *X*.

I define a subset of *X* as open if and only if it includes at least one neighborhood for each of its points.

But then any subset of *X* is open since *X* includes the neighborhood {*a*} for each point *a* of *X*. How can it not?

But then any subset of a metric space is an open set, which is totally insane since there would be no reason to introduce open sets in the first place!

What am I missing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and my apologies for not using the cool scripting language, but I don't think it matters much in this case.

Comment: The point $\{a\}$ is not a neighborhood of itself.  Note that, in your definition of *neighborhood*, you required that $r$ be positive.

Comment: The open ball $N(a,r)$ (by your notation) is the set of all points $x\in X$ such that $d(x,a)<r$. The point $a$ clearly belongs to this ball, but for most metric spaces $\{a\}$ is not the whole set $N(a,r)$, but just part of it. So you can't deduce that $\{a\}$ is a neighborhood.

Comment: To emphasize: the definition of $N(a,r)$ is not *some* points that satisfy $d(x,a)<r$, but *all* such points. Thus your argument that $\{a\}$ is a neighborhood of $a$ is not valid.

Comment: Put it right out in the open and I'll still find it! Awesome second comment and follow-on about not *some* but *all* . . . and so quick! Super! My proof which motivated the question in the first place is then flawed. Not a surprise! :-)

Comment: lulu wrote: "The point {} is not a neighborhood of itself."  This is not necessarily true. Notice that {a} *might* be a neighborhood of the point a; it depends on the metric space itself. (For instance, if the metric space is the set of integers with d(x,y) = |x-y|.)

Comment: Let the metric space be $\mathbb R$ with the standard metric and let the subset be $[0,1]$. Every neighborhood of $0$ contains negative numbers so how is that contained in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

I think You're missing the basic definition of open set in a metric space.

"A subset $A$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if $\forall x \in A, \exists r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$.

But you chose $r=0$ which makes every singleton open and hence every subset of the metric space a open set. Which need not be true